# Como poner una condicion en un programa que esta corriendo para que salga del programa (python)

Tags: python

Tengo un programa en python corriendo y me gustaria tener una condicion para que en cuanto yo pulse una tecla x el programa termine, se pause etc pero mientras que yo no pulse esa tecla el programa siga a lo suyo

Tengo un observable

```
mi_observable(keywords).pipe(
            operators.map(lambda txt: json.loads(txt)),
            operators.map(lambda d: parse_tweet(d))
        ).subscribe(on_error=lambda e: print(e))
```

```
def mi_observable(keywords):

    consumer_key = ""
    access_token = ""
    consumer_secret = ""
    access_token_secret = ""

    def observe_tweets(o, s):

        class TweetListener(StreamListener):

            def on_data(self, data):
                o.on_next(data)

            def on_error(self, status):
                o.on_error(status)

        listener = TweetListener()
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        global stream
        stream = Stream(auth, listener, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
        stream.filter(track=keywords, is_async=True, languages=['en'])

    return create(observe_tweets)
```

Y quiero usar algo asi para pararlo

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
       print('You Pressed A Key!')
       break
```

Pero no se muy bien donde ponerlo ni como parar un observable
Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, coloca el código que estas utilizando

Comment: hay una manera sencilla que seria con un break al final del if. Eso interrumpe y corta.

Comment: @maxin739  actualizado

Comment: Intentaste usar exit() ?

Comment: En vez de `break` usa `exit()`. La palabra reservada `break` sólo se usa en ciclos

Comment: Depende de tu sistema operativo puedes investigar cual es la forma de ejecutar comandos desde python para parar un proceso o programa. En cualquier caso utilizas la libreria os de python.